# error casting observable.subscribe

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

As shown in the following code, I am rceiving an error regarding the following line, because the casting is not correct

```
.subscribe((Consumer<? super List<String>>)getAnimalsObserver());
```

please let me know how to fix this issue.

**note**:

```
I am using the folloing rx versions
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.5'
```

**code**:

```
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.ObservableEmitter;
import io.reactivex.ObservableOnSubscribe;
import io.reactivex.Observer;
import io.reactivex.Scheduler;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;
import io.reactivex.functions.Consumer;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
getAnimalsObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe((Consumer<? super List<String>>)getAnimalsObserver());



 private Observer<String> getAnimalsObserver() {
    return new Observer<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onSubscribe->d: " + d);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String s) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onNext->s: " + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onError->e: " + e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onComplete");
        }
    };
}
```

**logcat**:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
com.example.pc_a.myapplication.MainActivity$1 cannot be cast to 
io.reactivex.functions.Consumer
at com.example.pc_a.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6288)
at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
t android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2642)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2754)
```

Comment: How is `getAnimalsObserver` implemented?

Comment: @akarnokd i updated the code..please have a look at it

Comment: But you still didn't show your getAnimalsObserver ().

Comment: @akarnokd I posted the required method..please have a look at it

Comment: Why are you casting it to `Consumer` in the first place? Don't cast and it should compile.

Comment: @akarnokd but when i dont cast it it will be underscored with red and the error says:cant resolve method subscribe(io.reactivex.Observer java.lang.String

Comment: @Anatolii i updated the code ...please have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to cast to `Consumer`. Secondly, you should modify your `Observer` as follows to make it work (`Observer` already can be used in `subscribe`). I simplified it a bit to make it neater:

```
private Observable<List<String>> getAnimalsObservable() {
    return Observable.fromArray(Arrays.asList(
        new String[]{
            "Ant", "Ape",
            "Bat", "Bee", "Bear", "Butterfly",
            "Cat", "Crab", "Cod",
            "Dog", "Dove",
            "Fox", "Frog"
        }
    ));
}

private Observer<List<String>> getObserver() {
    return new Observer<List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            //your logic here
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(List<String> values) {
            //your logic here
            for (String value : values) {
                System.out.print(value + " ");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            //your logic here
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            //your logic here
        }
    };
}

@Test
public void test() {
    // here you can add your observeOn and subscribeOn but they're not important for the test
    getAnimalsObservable()
        .subscribe(getObserver());
}
```

Output:

> Ant Ape Bat Bee Bear Butterfly Cat Crab Cod Dog Dove Fox Frog